# Parse.com array of pointers or PFRelation

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Help me please. I am working with social network app. I want create PFObject "Group". Users can follow it. But only other participants can add other users as members.

As I understand I can develop following feature with PFRelation class.
But tell me please, how can I develop feature with adding other users to group?User is protected class so I can't add PFRelation to another user. So only one way adding users to groups by another user is creation array of pointers?

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: There are two, distinct ideas: array of pointers and relation.  For members of a group numbering in the 100k, the only reasonable choice is a relation.

Comment: PFRelation is the way to go. Using an Array will make it so slow when making a query.

Comment: Thanks, guys. But could I add PFRelation from User1 to User2? PFUser is protected, so I can't add another user without his conformation right?

+ I can't understand how can I create query where user is participant

Comment: I found this http://blog.parse.com/2012/05/17/new-many-to-many/. So I can do the same queries as with array. Nice

Comment: change my question for clearly understanding the problem

Comment: You can create Group object with PFRelation field, then you add users to this relation.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to create a many-to-many relationship between users and groups and only users that are already members of a given group can add a new user to this group right ?

If so here is how I would do it...

1. Group creation

   ```
   // Create the group and add its creator as the sole group member
   PFUser * user = [PFUser currentUser];
   PFObject * group = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"Group"];
   PFRelation * members = [group relationForKey:@"members"];
   [members addObject:user];

   // Set an ACL so that the group is visible but only the 
   PFACL * acl = [PFACL ACL];
   [acl setPublicReadAccess:true];
   [acl setWriteAccess:true forUser: user];
   group.ACL = cal
   ```
2. Add a new group member

   ```
   PFUser * member = [PFUser currentUser];
   PFUser * candidate = ...; // not yet a member 
   PFObject * group = ...; // The group candidate wants to join
   PFRelation * members = [group relationForKey:@"members"];
   [members addObject:candidate];
   [group.ACL setWriteAccess:true forUser:candidate];
   ```

In step 2, member is a member of group and so has write access required to add a new user, candidate. 
After step 2, candidate is now a full member and has gained write access to the group.

However I have not tested this: 
- Does the relation "inherits" the ACL from the group ? Or anyone that can read the group, can access the relation and then add itself to the group ?

Also it seems hard to distinguish roles among members. I think that now any member could decide to delete the group...

You're probably better off enforcing the rules at application level.